# minted background color from left to right page side

Tags: color, minted, backgrounds, code, rendering

I use `minted` package to get syntax coloration with background color. I know it is highly printer-unfriendly but I use it.

My goal is to make the background rectangle color take the wool page width. But the code included have to stay inside the regular margins.

So, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{minted,xcolor}
\usemintedstyle{monokai}
\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828} % from https://github.com/kevinsawicki/monokai
\begin{document}

{Code Example:}

\begin{minted}[bgcolor=bg,
               frame=lines,
               framesep=2mm]{python}
    #!/usr/bin/env python2

    def example_function():
        return "hello world"

    a = 5
    b = "I am python code"
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

I would like to get the following rendering:

[image]

I try to make it with `tcolorbox` and `adjustbox`, but it doesn’t preserve the margin for the text.

So, how can I get this rendering?

## Edit :

I modify my MWE like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{minted,xcolor}
\usepackage{xcolor,eso-pic}
\usepackage[savepos]{zref}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\definecolor{bg}{HTML}{282828} % from https://github.com/kevinsawicki/monokai

\newenvironment{widthcode}%
{%
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable,size=tight,oversize,
  sharp corners,
  colback=blue,
  left=150pt,
  right=150pt,
  ]}%
{%
\end{tcolorbox}
}


\setminted[text]{breaklines}
\setminted{bgcolor=bg,
               linenos,
               breaklines,
               fontsize=\footnotesize}


\begin{document}

\begin{minted}{python}
#!/usr/bin/env python2

def example_function():
    return "hello world"

a = 5
b = "I am python code"
\end{minted}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{minted}{sh}
#!/bin/sh
# Simple line count example, using sh
#
# sh tutorial: http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial#8-2-read-file-into-bash-array
# My scripting link: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hwloidl/docs/index.html#scripting
#
# Usage: ./line_count.sh file
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Link filedescriptor 10 with stdin
exec 10<&0
# stdin replaced with a file supplied as a first argument
exec < $1
# remember the name of the input file
in=$1

# init
file="current_line.txt"
let count=0

# this while loop iterates over all lines of the file
while read LINE
do
    # increase line counter 
    ((count++))
    # write current line to a tmp file with name $file (not needed for counting)
    echo $LINE > $file
    # this checks the return code of echo (not needed for writing; just for demo)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
     then echo "Error in writing to file ${file}; check its permissions!"
    fi
done

echo "Number of lines: $count"
echo "The last line of the file is: `cat ${file}`"

# Note: You can achieve the same by just using the tool wc like this
echo "Expected number of lines: `wc -l $in`"

# restore stdin from filedescriptor 10
# and close filedescriptor 10
exec 0<&10 10<&-

mkvmerge --machin-chouette
\end{minted}

\lipsum[2]


\lipsum[2-4]
\begin{widthcode}
\begin{minted}{sh}
#!/bin/sh
# Simple line count example, using sh
#
# sh tutorial: http://linuxconfig.org/Bash_scripting_Tutorial#8-2-read-file-into-bash-array
# My scripting link: http://www.macs.hw.ac.uk/~hwloidl/docs/index.html#scripting
#
# Usage: ./line_count.sh file
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Link filedescriptor 10 with stdin
exec 10<&0
# stdin replaced with a file supplied as a first argument
exec < $1
# remember the name of the input file
in=$1

# init
file="current_line.txt"
let count=0

# this while loop iterates over all lines of the file
while read LINE
do
    # increase line counter 
    ((count++))
    # write current line to a tmp file with name $file (not needed for counting)
    echo $LINE > $file
    # this checks the return code of echo (not needed for writing; just for demo)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
     then echo "Error in writing to file ${file}; check its permissions!"
    fi
done

echo "Number of lines: $count"
echo "The last line of the file is: `cat ${file}`"

# Note: You can achieve the same by just using the tool wc like this
echo "Expected number of lines: `wc -l $in`"

# restore stdin from filedescriptor 10
# and close filedescriptor 10
exec 0<&10 10<&-

mkvmerge --machin-chouette
\end{minted}
\end{widthcode}

\end{document}
```

As you see, I create the `widthcode` environment witch put a large blue background from left to right page side.
This  `widthcode` work fine and allow page break for long texts :

[image]

But, when I put a `minted` environment in a `widthcode` one, it fail:
[image]

So, the question became: **how to make `minted` environment breakable in `tcolorbox` environment?**

Comment: does this answer help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/407209/how-to-force-a-colorbox-to-be-pagewidth?rq=1

Comment: Not realy but I find someting like this. I am writing a message.